# python class attribute scope - leak to global scope

Tags: python, oop, scope

I was quite surprised by some behavior that I saw when assigning an argument to a class attribute in python. Perhaps someone can enlighten me, and help me stop it from happening.

Essentially, the changes I make to the class attribute inside the class methods are being replicated in the global variable that was passed to the class **init** as an argument.

Is there a built in way to stop this sort of behavior, as in a lot of cases it may break the data variable for other uses down the line.

Here is a basic version of the code

```
class BasicClass:

    def __init__(self, data_raw):
        self.data = data_raw
        self.data['new_column'] = 1

# Now outside the class

data = pd.read_csv(...)

data.columns
Out[1]: ['orig_column']

obj = BasicClass(data)

data.columns
Out[2]: ['orig_column','new_column']
```

Comment: Try using data_raw.copy()?

Answer (score 0):

This is because both `self.data` and `data` are pointing to the same object.

If you want the a deep copy of a `list`, then

```
def __init__(self, data_raw):
    self.data = data_raw.copy()
    self.data['new_column'] = 1
```

Please do refer : [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)